# What formatting guidelines should I follow for my bachelor's thesis if some of them are not specified by the university?

Tags: thesis, formatting, netherlands

I am writing my bachelor's thesis at a university of applied sciences in the Netherlands.

The university has provided me with a document outlining some of the guidelines I should follow (like what format of citations is expected and what the document should look like overall), but it does not specify anything about, for example, fonts, font sizes and color schemes.

What is the correct approach to formatting in this case? Do things like fonts and font sizes matter very much or can I make that choice as long as it is reasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check other submissions and ask your mentor / supervisor. In any event, I would choose a font with spacing etc. that is clear and easy to read with suitable line spacing.

Some "cursive" fonts look nice but are not "easy" for extended reading.

Answer (score 2):

In general If the university did not specify a guideline for a particular issue, it is fair to assume you can make whatever reasonable choice you want for it. There is usually a step where the university checks the formatting of the final version (at least in the US), so be prepared to make some changes at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your supervisor and if you do not get a satisfying response than use a style similar to the most respected journal of your field.